# Floating point subtraction adds weird trailing value

Tags: python, floating-point, subtraction

I'm sure there is an answer out there but I just can't find it.

**Why does python add 0.000000000000000009 to this floating point subtraction?**

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 10 2016, 21:41:23)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1.01-1
0.010000000000000009
>>> 1.01-1.0
0.010000000000000009
>>> (1 + 0.01)-1
0.010000000000000009
>>>
```

Comment: Simply because floating points cannot represent `0.01` exactly.

Comment: Thanks @vaultah that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Actually the subtraction is exact. It's `1.01` that's already wrong. You can see it with `'%.60f' % 1.01`. And if you compare it with `'%.60f' % (1.01 - 1)`, you'll see that the actual difference is exactly 1.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't see what this has to do with `0.01`. That neither appears here as literal nor as result (`1.01 - 1 == 0.01` is `False`).